# Problems to create MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am trying to create this procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE PA_INCLUDE_SETTING
(IN SettingType INT(10),
IN SettingName INT(10),
IN Active INT(1),
OUT result INT(1))
BEGIN
    DECLARE exist INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO exist 
    FROM tbSetting 
    WHERE nmSetting = SettingName
    AND cdSettingType = SettingType;
    IF (exist > 0) THEN
        DECLARE active INT;
        SELECT cdActive INTO active 
        FROM tbSetting
        WHERE nmSetting = SettingName
        AND cdTypeSetting = SettingType;
        IF (active = 0) THEN
            UPDATE tbSetting 
            SET cdActive = 1
            WHERE nmSetting = SettingName
            AND cdSettingType = SettingType;
            SET result = -1;
        ELSE 
            SET result = -2;
        END IF;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO tbSetting 
        (cdSettingType, nmSetting, cdActive)
        VALUES (SettingType, Setting, Active);
        SET result = 0;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE tbSetting
 (
        cdSettingType INT(10) NOT NULL,
        cdSetting INT(10) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
        nmSetting VARCHAR(30),
        cdActive INT(1),
        CONSTRAINT pk_cdSetting PRIMARY KEY (cdSettingType, cdSetting )
  )
```

And I am receiving this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE active INT;
            SELECT cdActive
            FROM tbSetting
            WHERE n' at line 13
```

This is the first time I create an Stored Procedure with this kind of complexity and I don't understand why this error is appearing.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations should immediately follow the `begin` block.  So just move the declaration up to the beginning of the function:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE exist INT;
    DECLARE active INT;

    . . .
```

By the way, `exist` is a very bad name for a variable because it is very similr to a MySQL reserved word.

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice, this solved my problem!! In 7 minutes I will check your answer as correct! :)